# What does the "\b" mean in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was looking for some answers, but I couldn't find any. There is this code (from stackover flow) that I don't understand:

```
if re.search("\b{0}\b".format(w),line):
```

The "\b" is what I do not understand. What does it do?

Thanks!

I'm trying to make this login application by the way. So I'm trying to save
passwords.

Comment: That code is wrong. The `\b`s mean something entirely different from what the author wanted them to mean, because the author forgot to use the `r` prefix for a raw string literal.

Comment: Also, [please Google first](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+backslash+b). Typing out the names of special characters in the search often helps.

Comment: `\b` -> word boundary. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html